# fiware cygnus Docker Build failure

Tags: docker, fiware, fiware-cygnus

edited 
I try to install **cgynus-ngsi** firstly i install the ready made image and tested that it's worked fine,
but when  try  to reconfigure **agent.conf** i  edit the file  and  try  to  install  cgynus-ngsi from scratch it  found this  problem 
Trying other mirror.

```
Setting up Install Process
http://ftp.uma.es/mirror/CentOS/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://ftp.uma.es/mirror/CentOS/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://sunsite.rediris.es/mirror/CentOS/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://sunsite.rediris.es/mirror/CentOS/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.trueinter.net/centos/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirror.trueinter.net/centos/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.uv.es/mirror/CentOS/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirror.uv.es/mirror/CentOS/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp.cica.es/CentOS/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://ftp.cica.es/CentOS/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.tedra.es/CentOS/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirror.tedra.es/CentOS/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://centos.uvigo.es/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://centos.uvigo.es/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.airenetworks.es/CentOS/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirror.airenetworks.es/CentOS/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://centos.cadt.com/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://centos.cadt.com/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
ftp://ftp.cesca.cat/centos/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on ftp://ftp.cesca.cat/centos/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again
/bin/sh: java: command not found
```

then

i run tis commad 
**docker build -t cygnus-common** .
it git this logs

```
INFO: Java version <1.7.0>

INFO: Apache domain <http://archive.apache.org/dist/>
INFO: URL MAVEN <http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz>
INFO: URL FLUME <http://archive.apache.org/dist/flume/1.4.0/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin.tar.gz>
INFO: Download and install Maven and Flume...
```

but get timeout

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a network problem. Are your host behind a proxy?

You can try to access the mirrors manually, from the same host, as stated in [this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/439014/clear-os-always-showing-operation-too-slow-less-than-1-bytes-sec), and see what happens:

```
time wget http://sunsite.rediris.es/mirror/CentOS/6.9/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
```

If you also get problems, maybe you'll have to get in touch with your cloud provider.

If you are running in a CentOS, as explained [in this link from CentOS forum](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5137), you can add `http_caching=packages` to `/etc/yum.conf` file and run the command again.

Please read the link above for more details.

Comment: the cygnus is deployed in a vm on the cloud . so , i wouldn't be able to know whether it's behind a proxy . in addition i use an ubuntu vm not centos

Comment: What command are you running that is producing this error? Please edit your question with more details.

Comment: What is the first command you run, @ahmad ? Before `Setting up Install Process http://ftp.uma.es/mirror/Ce...` ?

Comment: Besides, I edited my answer, @ahmad . Did you do the test with wget command?